# Missing of gnome-panel applets after upgrade

Tags: 11.04, upgrade, gnome-panel, applet

After the upgrade to natty I am missing various applets for the gnome-panel. Thy do not appear in the »add to panel« dialog although they are probably installed. These do I miss:

- netspeed
- tomboy sensor-applet
- gnome-powermanager (to avoid power saving mode)
- and some others more

That's so annoying! Does anyone know how to get them running? It would also interesting if someone else has this issue, please tell..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now there seems to be an solution:

```
 sudo aptitude install gnome-panel-bonobo indicator-applet-appmenu indicator-applet-complete
```

This bring you back the old missing applets...